# How to display information from a referencing table?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is probably a very simple solution to this, but I couldn't figure out an appropriate way to google it. 
I have three tables in my database. 
The first one is "customer" and it has (ID, Name, Username etc)
The second one is "attraction" and it has (AttractionID, Name, Location, etc..)
The tird one "favourites" is made in order for the user to save favourites from the second table with the user ID from the first one:
Here is the third table:

```
CREATE TABLE Favorites (
  FavID INT NOT NULL,
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  AttractionID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (FavID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES customer(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (AttractionID) REFERENCES attraction(AttractionID)
);
```

I can insert into the table but what sql query do I need to use in order to show information from the referencing tables?
Lets say the user has saved their user ID and favourite attraction ID to the favourite table, how can I display the name and location from the attraction table that corespond to the foreign key attractionID saved in the favourites table?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use JOIN for it:

```
SELECT * FROM Favorites f 
INNER JOIN Attraction a ON f.AttractionId = a.AttractionId
INNER JOIN customer c ON f.Id = c.id
```

f, a and c are just aliases to make the referencing simpler, you could also write

```
SELECT * FROM Favorites 
INNER JOIN Attraction ON Favorites.AttractionId = Attraction.AttractionId
INNER JOIN customer ON Favorites.Id = customer.id
```

or with AS, which makes it a bit more clear (but longer, so I prefer the first way)

```
SELECT * FROM Favorites AS f 
INNER JOIN Attraction AS a ON f.AttractionId = a.AttractionId
INNER JOIN customer AS c ON f.Id = c.id
```

Comment: can you explain what "f" and "a" are for?

Comment: @user3565574 Explained.

Comment: I tried using this: $sql ="SELECT `Name`, `Location`
FROM `attractions`
INNER JOIN `favourites`
ON `ID`='$ID'";   But it prints out everythiing 14 times....

Comment: You are putting the condition incorrectly, `ON` is only specifying on which the table needs to be joined, so you probably want something like `SELECT Name, Location FROM attractions INNER JOIN favourites ON favourites.AttractionId = attractions.AttractionId WHERE favourites.ID = ...`, get it?